# Repeat 3d tensor's rows in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have a `BxCxd` tensor of coordinates and want to repeat each row in the following way:

```
 [[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]] -> [[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]]
```

In the above example each row is repeated 2 times. What's especially important is the ordering. Each row in the first tensor should appear k times in the second one before the next row appears.
I tried the following code:

```
print(x.size())
params = x.repeat_interleave(self.k, dim=-1).permute(0,2,1)
```

In the above snippet, `x` is of size `32x128x4` before `repeat_interleave`. With `self.k = 64` I would expect the result to be a `32x8192x4` tensor, however the result I am getting is `32x256x128` which does not make sense to me. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
t.repeat_interleave(2, dim=1)
```

Output:

```
ensor([[[1, 0, 0],
         [1, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: I'll probably sound insane, but i tried that exact thing a few minutes ago and it would not work. I tried it again and it works, go figure... Thank you very much!